# Как сохранить изображение которое отправил пользователь

Tags: python, telebot

Не могу понять почему возникает ошибка и ничего не сохраняется вот код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("1181859447:AAF6kJmz8eFSljDs06nZmMSgTx8-dPaU6yg")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
     try:

         file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
         downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

         src = 'C:/Users/kiber/PycharmProjects/Geek/GGWP' + file_info.file_path
         with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
             new_file.write(downloaded_file)
         bot.reply_to(message, "Фото добавлено")

     except Exception as e:
         bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Когда я отправляю боту картинку, но он отправляет мне в ответ вот такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне исправить эту ошибку и сохранить изображение в указную папку?

Comment: Потому что нет такого файла. Ван надо открывать файл для записи и если не существует создавать его -делается это с помощью `with open(src, 'wb+') as new_file:`. Так вы задаете создание файла если его не существует, если он существует, то будет перезаписан, а его предыдущее содержимое будет уничтожено

Comment: Не скачивает картинку

Comment: Путь не правильный, надо так - `src = 'C:/Users/kiber/PycharmProjects/Geek/GGWP/' + file_info.file_path`

Comment: Теперь выдаёт такую же ошибку ```[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/kiber/PycharmProjects/Geek/GGWP/photos/file_1.jpg'```

Comment: Ясно, он добавляет подкаталог `photos` в путь, просто измените формирование пути на : `src = 'C:/Users/kiber/PycharmProjects/Geek/GGWP/' + file_info.file_path.replace('photos/', '')`

Comment: Или создайте каталог `photos` в папке 'C:/Users/kiber/PycharmProjects/Geek/GGWP/

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!